# Ansible: build a string in a Jinja loop

Tags: loops, ansible

I would like to build a string in a Jinja loop for an output variable named `hostvariabletouseinawxworflow` (I'd like to use this variable in a later step in an Ansible AWX workflow w/: hosts: `{{ hostvariabletouseinawxworflow }}`).

When I define/build only one VM in my workflow, it's easy:

```
hostvariabletouseinawxworflow = vmname
```

But, when I'm building more than one VM, I would like to name them with an ascending number at the end. I'd like the first machine's name to omit the number, and only the following machine names to end with the number (so the sequence of machine names is `my-new-vm`, `my-new-vm-2`, `my-new-vm-3`, and so on). So the values of `hostvariabletouseinawxworflow` would be: `my-new-vm`, `my-new-vm-2` and so on... How can I do this kind of loop in a playbook task?

#### Scenario 1

```
input_vars:
  vmcount:1
  vmname: my-new-vm
```

`hostvariabletouseinawxworflow` should be: `my-new-vm`

#### Scenario 2

```
input_vars:
  vmcount:2
  vmname: my-new-vm
```

`hostvariabletouseinawxworflow` should be: `my-new-vm`, `my-new-vm-2`

#### Scenario 3

```
input_vars:
  vmcount:3
  vmname: my-new-vm
```

`hostvariabletouseinawxworflow` should be: `my-new-vm`, `my-new-vm-2`, `my-new-vm-3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following task should give you the output your looking for:

```
- set_fact:
    hostvariabletouseinawxworflow: {% for count in range(0, vmcount) %}{% if loop.first%}{{ vmname }}{% else %}{{ vmname }}-{{ loop.index }}{% endif %}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %} 
  vars:
    vmcount: 3
    vmname: my-new-vm
```

This returns:

```
TASK [debug] ********
ok: [localhost] => {
    "hostvariabletouseinawxworflow": "my-new-vm, my-new-vm-2, my-new-vm-3"
```

Note that it's possible to split the jinja across multiple lines for readability but it get tricky to deal with spaces and new line characters if you're doing it outside of a template file.

If you're not sure how the loop breaks down here it is split out:

```
{% for count in range(0, vmcount) %}
  {% if loop.first %}
    {{ vmname }}
  {% else %}
    {{ vmname }}-{{ loop.index }}
  {% endif %}

  {% if not loop.last %}
  , 
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach using [filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html).
Here `[vmname,] +` is specifically used to avoid generating `my-new-vm-1`.

*Assumption: vmcount is 1 or more.*

```
- set_fact:
    hostvariabletouseinawxworflow : "{{ ([vmname,] + [vmname,] | 
                                          product(range(2, vmcount+1)) | 
                                          map('join', '-') | list) | 
                                        join(', ') }}" 
  vars:
    vmcount: 3
    vmname: my-new-vm

- debug:
    var: hostvariabletouseinawxworflow
```

Outputs

```
"hostvariabletouseinawxworflow": "my-new-vm, my-new-vm-2, my-new-vm-3"
```

Comment: both worked! thank you very much for your great answers and time. to help others with a common approach with awx/tower and creating vsphere vms and deploy on in a workflow:1.workflow-node: create vms w/ terraform module on a dedicated 'setup/bastion' host. 2. node: refresh vsphere dynamic inventory 3. node: set the hostnames (like solved above) with set_stats 4-xx. use jobtemplates with:--hosts: "{{ hostvariabletouseinawxworflow| default('vsphere_vm_name') }}". problem with the vsphere inventory script atm is that it dosent reads tags/don't creates groups from tags so I needed this workaround.